# How to compress tiff image

Tags: java

I am currently storing the tiff image in BufferredImage during runtime and displaying the same in image src tag of hmtl.

My tiff image size is about 60kb and currently it takes approx 1 sec time to load in web browser.

Is there any way to compress the tiff image or BufferedImage so that the time to load the image in browser can be faster.

Below is my code for saving tiff image in BufferredImage.

```
public BufferedImage savetiff(File srcFilePath) throws IOException {
            FileSeekableStream stream = new FileSeekableStream(srcFilePath);
            TIFFDecodeParam decodeParam = new TIFFDecodeParam();

            decodeParam.setDecodePaletteAsShorts(true);
            ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();

            params.add(stream);
            RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);
            BufferedImage img = image1.getAsBufferedImage();

            return img;
    }
```

Code for converting tiff to image but in this code I have to save the jpeg image in disk and then I have to read it again. If there is any way to convert tiff to JPEG and save in BufferedImage.

```
public boolean tiff2JPG(File srcFilePath, File destFilePath) {
            boolean status = false;
            SeekableStream s = null;
            RenderedImage op = null;
            ImageDecoder dec = null;
            TIFFDecodeParam param = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            JPEGEncodeParam jpgparam = null;
            ImageEncoder en = null;
            try {
                    s = new FileSeekableStream(srcFilePath);
                    dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", s, param);
                    op = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(0);
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);
                    jpgparam = new JPEGEncodeParam();

                    jpgparam.setQuality(67);
                    en = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("jpeg", fos, jpgparam);
                    en.encode(op);
                    status = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    try {
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException io) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            io.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
return status;
```

Please advice.

Regards,
Dinesh Pise

Comment: Why TIFF? That's not intended to be a highly compressed browser friendly format.

Comment: One thing I almost always tell people to check is that there host allows gzip, this compresses the majority of content on a server making loading times quicker.

Comment: Could you not save as JPEG for speed reasons?

Comment: @AaronLee I tried out with converting tiff to jpeg but the size increases when I convert for eg tiff of 60kb size getting to 1700kb after converting to jpeg. I am editing my post and pasting the code for tiff to jpeg. One more thing I am uploading image during runtime in server.